# What line indicates that filebeat is creating an index in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

What line indicates that filebeat is creating an index in Elasticsearch. We are trying to debug the fact that its not creating an Elasticsearch index, but the harvester fails saying the index is missing. Isn't it the job of Filebeat to create this index when it starts, if so which lines in the logs `(obtained via kubectl logs <pod.id>)` indicate that it is getting created in the first place.

Error log shows this for Filebeat 7.7.x, 7.6.x ..

Could not init registrar: registry file version 1 not supported

Environment: Filebeat DaemonSet running in Kubernetes cluster

Its using this script https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/7.7/deploy/kubernetes/filebeat/filebeat-daemonset.yaml to run as a DaemonSet in a kubernetes environment. VERSION was set to 7.7.0
https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/7.7/deploy/kubernetes/filebeat/filebeat-daemonset.yaml#L23 and the error log has the above failure information.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the default [`ConfigMap` configuration](https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/7.7/deploy/kubernetes/filebeat/filebeat-configmap.yaml), there's no `index` setting specified, and hence, Filebeat will create a new index called `filebeat-%{[agent.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}` by default.

If you don't see an index of that name being created, it might be that Filebeat has nothing to read, i.e. that you have nothing in `/var/log/containers/*.log`...

Comment: default index creation is fine and there are logs in the containers, but the issue it could not init the registrar. Its not clear what is wrong with the configuration and how we should rectify it

Comment: You mentioned "We are trying to debug the fact that its not creating an Elasticsearch index" so as I understand your issue is that the index is not being created

Comment: apologize, index is not being created. but the real issue is the registrar error. there are logs and its able to pickit up properly, it works for 7.10.1 but not on 7.7.0